# Cannot resolve a single A Record from client machine

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, local, resolve

I set up a simple Bind server on my VPS and it is working properly.

The problem occurs with my local windows machines, which are connected to internet through the home router.

I created an A-record named 'dev' and it is invisible from my local network for some reason, though people from other locations can resolve dev.mydomain.com. Ironically, dev.mydomain.com cannot be resolved for myself only.

If I add another A-record, say, 'gamma' then it becomes visible from my local windows machines instantly. So this is just for that particular 'dev' name.

The only difference is that I had dev.mydomain.com server on another IP but that was a month ago; all nameservers have been changed since then. I tried to reboot my router and flushed dns cache on windows machines: no result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any entries in your hosts file? (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)

Comment: Yes I do but are irrelevant as far as I can judge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a cached negative hit? Try `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear the client cache.

**Edit:** Summing up the findings so far.

- You flushed the local DNS cache, so there weren't any cached negative responses. This means that the problem is not with your client.
- You queried the nameserver directly from the client and received a correct response. This means that the problem is also not with your nameserver.

The logical consequence is that the cause of the problem lies somewhere en route between your client and your nameserver.

Which DNS server(s) does your client use? (`ipconfig /all`) Is it your router? What happens when you configure a different nameserver on your client? (e.g. 8.8.8.8, one of Google's public nameservers)

Comment: As I noted in question I had already done that: no result...

Comment: Do you also get a negative result when you query your nameserver directly? `nslookup dev.mydomain.com a.b.c.d`, a.b.c.d being the IP address of your nameserver.

Comment: This is the result of this command:

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  a.b.c.d

Name:    dev.mydomain.com
Address:  a.b.c.d

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Well, the issue dissolved during the night. dev is now fully accessible. However, some new names cause the same issue. Some do, some don't. E.g. 'gamma' did not but 'alpha' did. To your question: DNS on my client is DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1, which is my router. On the router itself there is no DNS field, it is configured via login/password only somehow: I do not see the way to enter DNS.

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds very much like your router caching negative results, perhaps even past a reboot.